# Python:reduce list but keep details

Tags: python, list, reduce

say i have a list of items which some of them are similiar up to a point
but then differ by a number after a dot

```
['abc.1',
 'abc.2',
 'abc.3',
 'abc.7',
 'xyz.1',
 'xyz.3',
 'xyz.11',
 'ghj.1',
 'thj.1']
```

i want to to produce from this list a new list which collapses multiples but preserves some of their data, namely the numbers suffixes 
so the above list should produce a new list

```
[('abc',('1','2','3','7'))
 ('xyz',('1','3','11'))
 ('ghj',('1'))
 ('thj',('1'))]
```

what I have thought, is the first list can be split by the dot into pairs
but then how i group the pairs by the first part without losing the second

I'm sorry if this question is noobish, and thanks in advance

...
wow, I didnt expect so many great answers so fast, thanks

Comment: Your initial list is not valid Python code.  Should those be strings?

Comment: yes, those are strings ,i didnt mean it to be code, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the list with a separator function, use `itertools.groupby` with a key that takes the first element, and collect the second element into the result.

```
from itertools import groupby, imap

list1 = ["abc.1", "abc.2", "abc.3", "abc.7", "xyz.1", "xyz.3", "xyz.11", "ghj.1", "thj.1"]

def break_up(s):
    a, b = s.split(".")
    return a, int(b)

def prefix(broken_up): return broken_up[0]
def suffix(broken_up): return broken_up[1]

result = []
for key, sub in groupby(imap(break_up, list1), prefix):
    result.append((key, tuple(imap(suffix, sub))))

print result
```

Output:

```
[('abc', (1, 2, 3, 7)), ('xyz', (1, 3, 11)), ('ghj', (1,)), ('thj', (1,))]
```

Comment: Note that unlike solutions based on `defaultdict`, this solution allocates no additional storage of the size of the input list. (Except of course the resulting list, but that can be easily avoided by yield-ing the values instead of appending them to a list.)

Comment: this is a very interesting solution, i need to learn a bit more about functional programming to fully understand this solution,

Comment: groupby(sequence, keyfun) takes the sequence and groups it by elements that look the same, according to the keyfun. What you get out of it are consecutive pairs of (key, elements...). This solution uses `imap` to decompose list elements into constituents - the prefix (first) and the suffix (second). It then tells `groupby` to group list items by prefix, but to retain all the suffixes. Despite the verbiage, this solution seems closest to the spirit of the original question.

Comment: I've now cosmetically edited the code to appear a bit less "functional" (no `lambda`) and to improve the naming to make it clearer what's going on.

Comment: i think i got it now, i need to go over itertools, it seems a very powerfull tool. thank you!

Comment: Reverting martineau's edit, except for the variable name. A list comprehension is much less clear to a beginner, and harder to convert to other kind of processing, such as simply printing the items without collecting them.

Answer (score 5):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for el in elements:
    key, nr = el.split(".")
    d[key].append(nr)

#revert dict to list
newlist = d.items()
```

Comment: +1: I think this is a good example of a case where the straightforward iterative solution is significantly better than the alternatives.